# Highchart show grid lines on y-axis for every point

Tags: highcharts, angular6

I'm using highchart column chart. In that my y axis max value is 10 and min values is 0. I want to show grid lines for every points from 0 - 10. If height of chart is less than 185px it is showing only five grid lines and if it is greater that 185 px it is showing grid lines for all points. I tried by setting tick interval but minimum I set tick interval to 0.1 it is showing only 8 grid lines. 
My y axis code is

```
yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      tickInterval: 0.1,
      title: {
        text: '',
        align: 'high'
      },
      labels: {
        x: 1,
        y: 3,
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.pos === 0 || this.pos === 5 || this.pos === 10) {
            return this.pos;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How can i force it to display all the gridlines for every point? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In API we can read:

> **tickInterval: number**
>
> ...
>
> If the tickInterval is too dense for labels to be drawn, Highcharts
>   may remove ticks.
>
> ...

To show all ticks use `tickAmount` property:

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    tickAmount: 11
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oqu8hkn9/

**API:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount

Comment: Thank you so much. Today you helped me to solve two problems. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the gridLine properties to achieve what you are after.

Here is an example with 10 gridLines, shown always. This is configured like this:

```
yAxis: {
  minorGridLineWidth: 1,
  minorTickInterval: 1,
  gridLineWidth: 0,
  ...
}
```

**Working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/1cm6qd0n/8/

**API on gridLines:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minorGridLineWidth